# Ajax Return Value show on div but not show on input fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

Hi I have AJAX code which can change the innerHTML of a `div` perfectly but it does not work for an input text field.

This is the AJAX code:

```js
<script>
function hallprice(str) {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("hallcharges").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url();?>admin/hallreservation/get_hallprice?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="hallcharges"></div>

<input id="hallcharges" name="hallcharges" type='text'  class="form-control" />
```

How do I update the text field with the `responseText`?

Comment: change innerHTML  to value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have same ID for `div` and `input`, please change `div` id to divHallcharges

if you want to show output in input use `document.getElementById("hallcharges").value`  instead of `document.getElementById("hallcharges").innerHTML`

```
<div id="divHallcharges"></div>

<input id="hallcharges" name="hallcharges" type='text'  class="form-control" />

<script>
function hallprice(str) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("hallcharges").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url();?>admin/hallreservation/get_hallprice?q="+str,true);

    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: thanks its now working fine. can you please tell me how to setup for multi responsetext like we have 2 input field but its have different data like .<input id="hallcharges" name="hallcharges" type='text'  class="form-control" />  <input id="menucharges" name="menucharges" type='text'  class="form-control" />

Comment: @SameedAlam can you add JSfiddle for your question? if you have multiple results, I would return JSON object/array in my response and in JavaScript I would fetch data from JSON object/array.

Comment: ok check this https://jsfiddle.net/gmqdbhrw/1/ we have 2 input fields but we have one  document.getElementById("hallcharges").value = xmlhttp.responseText; this return result for one input hallcharges i want its work also for second input field menuchagres how can i do

Comment: @SameedAlam update [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmqdbhrw/2/) , from php return JSON object {hallCharges:'x.x', menuCharges:'y.y'}, and check line 12-14 from fiddle

Comment: sir we use only one function for both variable get public function <?php get_hallprice(){

  $gethall = $this->input->get('q', TRUE);
  $hallprice = array();
  $this->load->model('hallreservation_model');

  $hallprice = $this->hallreservation_model->gethallprice($gethall);

  foreach ($hallprice as $value) {
  echo $value->itemprice;
  }

 }?>       in this how to we return for json for two different

Comment: @SameedAlam use [json_encode](http://nz.php.net/json_encode) ... send hallcharges and menu charges in same json object

Answer (score 1):

Inputfields doesnt take innerHTML, you have to set its value instead.

```
document.getElementById("hallcharges").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I might also mention that if you intend for two field (in this case, a div and a input field) to have the same ID you should use class instead, as IDs are unique and should only appear once on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the value of the input instead of innerhtml.

Try this..

```
document.getElementById("hallcharges").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```